# Cant get instagram access_token

Tags: curl, terminal, instagram, access-token

Looks guys, I have

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
 -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
 -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
 -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
 -F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

all mentioned fields. It is said that  I have to enter these to terminal.
The question is where in terminal I must enter these code ? . Did they meen command promt. What a terminal?

Comment: Where have you got this terminal command? You can port that example above to PHP if you have knowledge with PHP

Comment: They mean unix (or *nix) terminal (of course curl must be setup). This is a base example. Of course you should change it to your language.

Comment: For help with the access_token - I wrote up a quick blog post: http://www.benrlodge.com/blog/post/how-to-generate-an-instagram-access-token

Answer (score 0):

In linux terminal you need to enter the command to get the access token. For that first you need curl to be installed in your machine. curl available for windows also. For more about curl refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).